# How can I set 4 items per row? (PHP/HTML/CSS) non table

Tags: php, html, css, layout, printing

I want to print out the result can be each column have fixed row, like each row have 4 elements

> My code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

<head>
    <title>Print your data</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


    <style>
        * {
            font-family: Arial;
        }
        p.inline {
            display: inline-block;
        }
        span { 
            font-size: 13px;
        }
        .grid-container { 
            position: relative;
            display: inline-block; 
        }
        .a { 
            position: relative;
            display: inline-block;
            margin: 15px;
        }
        .print {
            margin-top: 10px;
            background-color: navy;
            color: white;
        }
        .print:hover {
            color: white;
            background-color: black;
        }
    </style>

    <style type="text/css" media="print">
        @page 
        {
            size: auto;   /* auto is the initial value */
            margin: 1mm;  /* this affects the margin in the printer settings */

        }
        .grid-container { 
            position: relative;
            display: inline-block;
        }
        .a { 
            position: relative;
            display: inline-block;
            margin: 15px;
        }
        .print {
            display: none;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="col text-center">
        <button onclick="window.print();" class="print btn btn-lg">Print your data</button>
    </div>
    <div style="margin: 1%">

            <?php
            require 'vendor/autoload.php';

                $row = 1;
                if (($csvfile = fopen($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], "r")) !== FALSE) {
                    while (($csvdata = fgetcsv($csvfile, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE) {

                        $colcount = count($csvdata);

                        //Skip the CSV first line, start read from second line
                        if($row == 1) {

                            $row++; continue; 
                        }

                        if($colcount!=5) {
                            $error = 'Column count incorrect';
                        } else {

                            $imageData = base64_encode(file_get_contents($csvdata[4]));
                            $generator = new \Picqer\Barcode\BarcodeGeneratorPNG();
                                echo '<div class="grid-container">';
                                echo '<div class="a">
                                      <img src="data:image;base64,'.$imageData.'" width="50"/>
                                      <div><b>Item: '.$csvdata[0].'</b></div>
                                      <div>
                                      <img src="data:image/png;base64,' . base64_encode($generator->getBarcode("$csvdata[1]", $generator::TYPE_CODE_128)) . '"/>
                                      <div><b>'.$csvdata[1].'</b></div>
                                      </div>
                                      <span><b>Price: '.$csvdata[2].'</b></span>
                                      <div>
                                      <span><b>Desc: </b>'.$csvdata[3].'</span>
                                      </div>
                                      </div></div>';
                        }
                    }
                    fclose($csvfile);
                }
            ?>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Right now the printing result:

image of the result:
[image: image of the result]

---

I want the printing result:

I want the result image 1:
[image: I want the result image 1]

I want the result image 2:
[image: I want the result image 2]

---

I checked online the example, but most of the example is have different `<tr>` tag, but mine is not like a table, I only have one value want to show.

So, in this case how can I make it the printing layout is fixed the width of each elements and can fixed number of each row elements?

Answer (score 0):

I think you may be well-served by simply using a 4-column table. Example:

```
<table>
  <thead>
   <tr>
     <th>Header 1</th>
     <th>Header 2</th>
     <th>Header 3</th>
     <th>Header 4</th>
   </tr>
</thead>
  <tr>
    <td>Cell1 </td>
    <td>Cell2 </td>
    <td>Cell3 </td>
    <td>Cell 4</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
     <td>Row 2, Cell1</td>
     <td>Row 2, C2</td>
     <td>Row 2, C3</td>
     <td>Row 2, C4</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Each TR will have as Many TDs as is needed for columns in your table. Each TR is a row.

For a more advanced method, you may be able to use [flexbox](https://www.w3schools.com/css/tryit.asp?filename=trycss3_flexbox_flex-wrap_wrap) with fixed-width containers.

Comment: But I am not using table to finish my code, so I want to know can I use other way to fix the width of my value?

Answer (score 0):

Here's a couple ways you could do this.

First with css, e.g. you could have each one set to width 20% and put them inside a container using display: flex like so:

```css
.container { display: flex; flex-wrap: wrap; }
.each { width: 20%; }
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="each">1</div>
  <div class="each">2</div>
  <div class="each">3</div>
  <div class="each">4</div>
  <div class="each">5</div>
  <div class="each">1</div>
  <div class="each">2</div>
  <div class="each">3</div>
  <div class="each">4</div>
  <div class="each">5</div>
  <div class="each">1</div>
  <div class="each">2</div>
  <div class="each">3</div>
  <div class="each">4</div>
  <div class="each">5</div>
</div>
```

Second way, using PHP way you could solve this using the % modulo operator.
Find out more about this here: https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.arithmetic.php

e.g. before the loop set an index e.g. $i = 0;
and then for each row increment it with $++;
Under this you can then in your code detect if this is the first of the 5 with `if ($i % 5 === 1)` and for the last row in the 5 you can use `if ($i % 5 === 0)`

In these if statements you could break the blocks onto a new line or break up how any container div rows you need to etc.

However I think the css way is the simplest and better way to do this of the 2 provided.
Hope this helps.

Comment: I tried your css way, but mine result is only one row in each elements, show like a line. If I use PHP way to do, why I should put the two code? I am new to PHP. Thank you.

Comment: Hi @KC-L, no worries. One other thing to try with the css way if you haven't already is try replacing `<div style="margin: 1%">` with `<div class="grid-container">` & take out the echo for the <div class="grid-container"> inside the loop as well as the last closing </div> echo'd inside too, this way it's a container around the entire grid. Rather than each element.
Then set my .container css to your .grid-container, and my .each css to your .a class.

Comment: Or with the php way, you could for example put a <br> in after every 5th element with `if ($i % 5 === 0) echo '<br>';`, that will break it onto a new line.

Comment: With the php way, you mean is it in the `if($colcount!=5)` before, I should add`$i=0;`, and then at the end I should add `$i++`? `

Comment: Looking back over your code, I guess we could use $row instead of $i, but change it and the if statement checking for the first row from 1 to 0. Then at the bottom of the while loop you'd need to run $row++;

Comment: I am so sorry, do you mind to show me the code in your answer? Thank you so much.

Comment: No worries, I can't atm but my advice would be to try out the css option as I think that will fit better anyway. Or play around with the php way mentioned, try using var_dump() as a way to show your $row counter at each point in your loop to see what happens. Hope this helps.